# How to add transparent rectangle panel on other component in java like it should look like same how we select anything on mouse pressed

Tags: java, swing

I just providing my small Example code here what I'm trying to do is I just want to show that multiple selection of `JLabel`s on the panel, I can able to select but that transparentpanel line will go back of the label not on the label while selecting...

```
package dharma;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SelectionRectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SelectionRectangle();
    }

    public SelectionRectangle() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                }
                catch ( UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) 
                {

                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                //  frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                BackgroundPane backgroundPane =new BackgroundPane();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(backgroundPane);
                //      frame.setGlassPane(backgroundPane);
                frame.setResizable( true );
                frame.pack();
                frame.setBounds(getScreenViewableBounds());
                //  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                //      frame.setGlassPane(backgroundPane);
                frame.setBounds(100,50,800, 500);
                frame.getContentPane().add(backgroundPane);


            }

        });
    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {
        int labelX, labelY, label2X, label2Y, label3X, label3Y, labelWidth,labelHeight;
        int mousePressedXValue;
        int mousePressedYValue;
        int mouseReleasedXValue;
        int mouseReleasedYValue;

        private BufferedImage background;
        private Point mouseAnchor;
        private Point dragPoint;

        private SelectionPane selectionPane;
        private ComponentSelection cs;

        public BackgroundPane() {

            selectionPane = new SelectionPane();


            setLayout ( null );
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBounds(50,50,100,100);
            add(label);

            labelX = label.getX();
            labelY = label.getY();
            labelWidth = label.getWidth();
            labelHeight = label.getHeight();

            JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
            label2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            label2.setOpaque(true);
            label2.setBounds(180,150,100,150);
            add(label2); 

            label2X = label2.getX();
            label2Y = label2.getY();

            JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
            label3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            label3.setOpaque(true);
            label3.setBounds(300,150,200,200);
            add(label3); 

            label3X = label3.getX();
            label3Y = label3.getY();

            System.out.println("LabelX:\t "+labelX);
            System.out.println("LabelY:\t "+labelY);

            System.out.println("Label2X:\t "+label2X);
            System.out.println("Label2Y:\t "+label2Y);

            System.out.println("Label3X:\t "+label3X);
            System.out.println("Label3Y:\t "+label3Y);

            //   cs = new ComponentSelection();
            try {
                Robot bot = new Robot();
                background = bot.createScreenCapture(getScreenViewableBounds());
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SelectionRectangle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            setLayout(null);

            add(selectionPane);


            //   add(cs);

            MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    mouseAnchor = e.getPoint();

                    mousePressedXValue = (int) mouseAnchor.getX();
                    mousePressedYValue = (int) mouseAnchor.getY();

                    System.out.println("Mouse xValue :\t "+ mousePressedXValue);
                    System.out.println("Mouse yValue:\t" + mousePressedYValue);

                    dragPoint = null;
                    selectionPane.setLocation(mouseAnchor);
                    selectionPane.setSize(0,0);


                    repaint();
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    mouseReleasedXValue = e.getX();
                    mouseReleasedYValue = e.getY();
                    if (( labelX > mousePressedXValue) 
                            && ( labelY > mousePressedYValue) 
                            && (labelX+labelWidth < mouseReleasedXValue) 
                            && (labelY+labelHeight < mouseReleasedYValue ))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Label 1 is selected");
                        System.out.println("Coming inside");

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println(" Not Coming inside Else");
                        System.out.println("Remaining labels is selected");
                    } 
                    System.out.println("Mouse Released X: " + mouseReleasedXValue);
                    System.out.println("mouseReleased Y "+ mouseReleasedYValue);
                    repaint();

                }
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    dragPoint = e.getPoint();
                    //    System.out.println("Mouse Release positions:\t"+ dragPoint);
                    int width = dragPoint.x - mouseAnchor.x;
                    int height = dragPoint.y - mouseAnchor.y;

                    int x = mouseAnchor.x;
                    int y = mouseAnchor.y;
                    //  System.out.println("mouseAnchor:\t"+x);

                    if (width < 0) {
                        x = dragPoint.x;
                        width *= -1;
                    }
                    if (height < 0) {
                        y = dragPoint.y;
                        height *= -1;
                    }
                    selectionPane.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                    selectionPane.revalidate();
                    //  cs.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                    //   cs.revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }


            };
            addMouseListener(adapter);
            addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
        }



        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            //  g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class SelectionPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton button;
        private JLabel label;
        //    private ComponentSelection cs;

        public SelectionPane() {
            setOpaque(true);

        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(new Color(128, 128, 128, 64));
            //g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            float dash1[] = {10.0f};
            BasicStroke dashed =
                    new BasicStroke(3.0f,
                            BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                            BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER,
                            10.0f, dash1, 0.0f);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.setStroke(dashed);
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 3, getHeight() - 3);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds() {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        return getScreenViewableBounds(gd);
    }

    public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds(GraphicsDevice gd) {
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (gd != null) {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            bounds = gc.getBounds();

            Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);

            bounds.x += insets.left;
            bounds.y += insets.top;
            bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
            bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);
        }
        return bounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) and look at the glass pane

Comment: Every pane in Swing has a GlassPane, whose purpose is catching mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:
In Java 1.7.0+, you can use the [`JLayer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayer.html).

[image]

```
//package dharma;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class SelectionRectangle2 {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JPanel backgroundPane = makeBackgroundPane();
    JLayer<JPanel> layer = new JLayer<>(
        backgroundPane, new SelectionRectangleLayerUI());

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    //f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(layer);
    f.setSize(640, 640);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
  public static JPanel makeBackgroundPane() {
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setName("label 1");
    label1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    label1.setOpaque(true);
    label1.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    label2.setName("label 2");
    label2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    label2.setOpaque(true);
    label2.setBounds(180, 150, 100, 150);

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    label3.setName("label 3");
    label3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    label3.setOpaque(true);
    label3.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 200);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(null);
    p.add(label1);
    p.add(label2);
    p.add(label3);
    return p;
  }
}

class SelectionRectangleLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {
  private int mousePressedXValue;
  private int mousePressedYValue;
  private int mouseReleasedXValue;
  private int mouseReleasedYValue;
  private Point mouseAnchor;
  private Point dragPoint;
  private Rectangle selectionPane = new Rectangle();

  @Override public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    super.paint(g, c);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(new Color(128, 128, 128, 64));
    //g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
    g2d.fill(selectionPane);

    float dash1[] = {10.0f};
    BasicStroke dashed =
      new BasicStroke(3.0f,
                      BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                      BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER,
                      10.0f, dash1, 0.0f);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.setStroke(dashed);
    //g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 3, getHeight() - 3);
    g2d.draw(selectionPane);
    g2d.dispose();
  }
  @Override public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      ((JLayer) c).setLayerEventMask(
          AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK
        | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
    }
  }
  @Override public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      ((JLayer) c).setLayerEventMask(0);
    }
    super.uninstallUI(c);
  }
  @Override protected void processMouseEvent(
      MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JPanel> l) {
    switch (e.getID()) {
    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
      mouseAnchor = e.getPoint();
      mousePressedXValue = (int) mouseAnchor.getX();
      mousePressedYValue = (int) mouseAnchor.getY();
      dragPoint = null;
      selectionPane.setLocation(mouseAnchor);
      selectionPane.setSize(0, 0);
      l.repaint();
      break;
    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:
      mouseReleasedXValue = e.getX();
      mouseReleasedYValue = e.getY();
      for (Component c : l.getView().getComponents()) {
        if (selectionPane.contains(c.getBounds())) {
          System.out.println(c.getName() + " is selected");
        }
      }
      l.repaint();
      System.out.println();
      break;
    }
  }
  @Override protected void processMouseMotionEvent(
      MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JPanel> l) {
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
      dragPoint = e.getPoint();
      int width = dragPoint.x - mouseAnchor.x;
      int height = dragPoint.y - mouseAnchor.y;

      int x = mouseAnchor.x;
      int y = mouseAnchor.y;
      if (width < 0) {
        x = dragPoint.x;
        width *= -1;
      }
      if (height < 0) {
        y = dragPoint.y;
        height *= -1;
      }
      selectionPane.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
      l.repaint();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot its working, if i want to show highlighted border which got selected with cursor at the corners and it should move how can i do tht

Comment: Thank's a lot im just beginner of java .u solved my problem thank u